# Debugging with Chrome in Parallels is incredibly slow or completely freezes

Tags: google-chrome, parallels

I'm using Parallels 10 with a Win 8.1 install on a MacBook pro i7 2.5ghz/16gb ram set up for software development. In one of the projects I'm working on, if I use Chrome for debugging and hit a breakpoint in the JS, the browser will often slow down to the point of being unusable or it will lock up completely (to the point of needing to be force closed). This same thing happens in the event that a loading spinner I'm using gets stuck spinning (because of an error in the JS or something on the server side). Is it me or is Chrome performance just horrible with Parallels? Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: first guess would be 'get more RAM' - but we'd really need more details to even hope for a second guess...

Comment: The VM is already getting 8gb RAM allocated to it

Comment: retract that, I re-read the question ;-) In which case, I'd check Windows' swapping - it is independent of the Mac.